# Tell Launchpad what DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS to use when building PPA package

Tags: ppa, launchpad

When I generate and upload source packages to my PPA, what's the best way to pass DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS that Launchpad will use when building binary versions of the package?

In particular, I want to pass in the "nodocs" option so that the documentation isn't built.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PPAs do not have a way to specify an environment variables (including `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS`) unfortunately. Until they do, you will need to edit the `debian/rules` file and set it manually yourself near the top (but not the first line if it uses a "#!"):

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nodocs
```

Optionally, just find the section of the `rules` file that looks for "nodocs" and change it to do what you need it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Set it in your debian/rules file.

Comment: What to set would be benficial. Esp some links.

Comment: @Manish Sinha: the question was HOW to set it, not what to set it to.  He already said he wants to set it to "nodocs".